Quota error in Terraform Firebase Authentication Identitytoolkit
I was trying to follow the Terraform Guide on Firebase
but I am always ending up with the same error with my firebase authentication on terraform apply
 Error: Error creating Config: googleapi: Error 403: Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The identitytoolkit.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default. To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds .
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "consumer": "projects/1234567",
│       "service": "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED"
│   }
│ ]
│ 
│   with google_identity_platform_config.default,
│   on main.tf line 68, in resource "google_identity_platform_config" "default":
│   68: resource "google_identity_platform_config" "default" {

Creating the project in firebase works fine, also also stuff like firestore (which I excluded from this sample), but the authentication does not work.
The error message looks quite clear, but I can not find anything in the documentation where to "set a quota" in terraform.
Here is the main.tf:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google-beta = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "~> 4.84.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google-beta" {
  user_project_override = true
}

provider "google-beta" {
  alias = "no_user_project_override"
  user_project_override = false
}

resource "google_project" "default" {
  provider   = google-beta.no_user_project_override
  name       = "My Terraform Test"
  project_id = "myterraformtest1"
  billing_account = var.billing_account 

  labels = {
    "firebase" = "enabled"
  }
}

resource "google_project_service" "default" {
  provider = google-beta.no_user_project_override
  project  = google_project.default.project_id
  for_each = toset([
    "cloudbilling.googleapis.com",
    "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
    "firebase.googleapis.com",
    "serviceusage.googleapis.com",
    "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com", 
  ])
  service = each.key
  disable_on_destroy = false
}

resource "google_firebase_project" "default" {
  provider = google-beta
  project  = google_project.default.project_id
  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.default
  ]
}

resource "google_identity_platform_config" "default" {
  project = google_project.default.project_id
  autodelete_anonymous_users = true
  sign_in {
    allow_duplicate_emails = true
    email {
        enabled = true
        password_required = false
    }
  }
   quota {
    sign_up_quota_config {
      quota = 1000
      start_time = ""
      quota_duration = "7200s"
    }
  }

  authorized_domains = [
    "localhost",
    "${google_project.default.project_id}.firebaseapp.com",
    "${google_project.default.project_id}.web.app",
  ]
  depends_on = [google_project_service.default]
}


A solution was added where I found your question. https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/quota-error-in-terraform-firebase-authentication-identitytoolkit/66714/4. For me what worked is
provider "google-beta" {
  project               = var.project_id
  billing_project       = var.project_id
  user_project_override = true
}

as I was using the beta provider.
